# python cp819 byte by byte

Tags: python, codec

(as recommended, creating a new question)

I have a file downloaded from the www with rather muddy content, so that I need to read it byte by byte and parse "artisanally". (well, there may perhaps be other solutions, but I also consider the parsing a good exercise). The file being coded in CP819, I was able to read it line by line with codecs.open - but I equally got the recommendation that this is not the right way to read a file byte by byte. What then is?

```
with codecs.open(INFIL, 'ru','cp819') as INPUT:
 DUMMY=INPUT.readline() ; print (DUMMY.encode('utf-8'))

 c=INPUT.read(1)
 print ("z {} ".format(c.encode('utf-8')))
```

The readline produced a complete line of input, as expected ; but the read(1) instead of giving me 1 character, gave me an entire line, broken only by one of the muddy characters.

Comment: Can't you just open it in raw mode and, you know, `.read` it? What's all this encoding for if you just want the bytes?

Answer (score 0):

If the file is mixed with cp819-encoded data and binary data, you should not use `codecs.open`. Open the file with binary mode, decode line that contains text only. (assuming you know the line that contains the cp819-encodied text)

```
with open(INFIL, 'rb') as INPUT:
    DUMMY = INPUT.readline()
    print (DUMMY.decode('cp819').encode('utf-8'))
    a_byte = INPUT.read(1)
    print ("z {}: {}".format(a_byte, ord(a_byte))
```

Comment: Sorry, readline is NOT useable - as said, there are junky bytes interspersed here and there and these include some \x0a and \x0d but should not be considered line terminators, not even field terminators. So I think I do need a way to get one byte at a dummy, first check how to treat it, and only if decide to keep it, apply decoding to it. As I read your reply, it seems I would best read byte by byte, construct cp819-coded words from it, and convert those to utf-8, right?

Comment: @Karlchen9, Could you show the sample data? (output of `print(repr(INPUT.read()))` if possible)

Comment: I am extremely reluctant to show the input data, because it will trigger at least one false positive: the input once started as csv, and surely all the horde will be crying that there is a csv library for python. Yes there is, I know, I spent hours and hours on that one. The data I have is so muddy that it can't cope. Please believe me. Besides, I would really like to try my hand at the parsing, I think it a good Python beginner's exercise. Allow me to insist on an exact answer to the exact question: """how to read byte by byte from a cp819-coded file?"""

Comment: @Karlchen9, You can still use `readline` (without `decode`). You  can iterate the byte-string, and it will yield byte-by-byte.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious way, if I'm not misunderstanding, is just:

```
from functools import partial

with open("/home/joshua/f.dat", "rb") as input:
    for byte in iter(partial(input.read, 1), b''):
        do_stuff_with(byte)
```

If you need something faster, try:

```
from functools import partial

with open("/home/joshua/f.dat", "rb") as input:
    for block in iter(partial(input.read, 1024), b''):
        for byte in block:
            do_stuff_with(byte)
```

Note that the first will give length-1 byte strings and the second will give integers on Python 3.